# Issue with generating a mysql import statement from the contents of an Oracle query

Tags: mysql, oracle, insert, export

I've almost got the query below working, however the two fields qcare_end and warranty_end both generate an invalid identifier error when executing the script
Also - i'm hoping to use this script (and a couple like it) to generate a series of operations that will take a subset of data from our oracle contract and part management database and squirt it into a mysql database which we use in support when logging incidents

```
    Select
    'Insert Into mysqldbtable (system_id, customer_code,, serial_no, system_type, description, qcare_end, warranty_end) Values (''' 
    || system_id || ''',''' || customer_code || ''',''' || serial_no || ''',''' || system_type || ''',''' || description ||  ''')'
  FROM (SELECT SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_ID
               --            ,SYSTEMS.SITE_NAME
              , CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.CUSTOMER_CODE
               --            , CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.NAME
              , SYSTEMS.SERIAL_NO
              , SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_TYPE
              , PM.DESCRIPTION
               --            ,MAX(EI.END_DATE)
              , TO_DATE(NULL) AS "qcare_end"
              , MAX(systems.warranty_end) AS "warranty_end"
        --            ,systems.warranty_code
          FROM LEO.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES
               -- , LEO.CUSTOMERS CUSTOMERS
              , LEO.SYSTEMS SYSTEMS
               -- , LEO.EXHIBIT_ITEMS EI
              , LEO.PART_MASTER PM
         WHERE SYSTEMS.ADDRESS_CODE = CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.ADDRESS_CODE
              -- AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.CUSTOMER_CODE = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_CODE 
              -- AND SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_ID = EI.SYSTEM_ID
           AND SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_TYPE = PM.PART_NO
         GROUP BY SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_ID,
                  SYSTEMS.SERIAL_NO,
                  CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.CUSTOMER_CODE,
                  CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.NAME,
                  SYSTEMS.SITE_NAME,
                  SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_TYPE,
                  PM.DESCRIPTION
        HAVING(SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_TYPE NOT IN('COMPLETE', 'ESSENTIAL', 'LOAN DEMO', 'LOAN CUSTOMER', 'MISC', 
        'ORPH-CHILD-SYS', 'ORPH_CHILD_SYS', 'PROD-BOM', 'QCARE', 'QSUPPORT', 'SPARES', 'STANDARD', 'WARRANTY', 'SOFT CARE')) 
        AND (SYSTEMS.SITE_NAME NOT LIKE '%DO NOT USE%' AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.NAME NOT LIKE 'QUANTEL%' AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.NAME NOT LIKE '%LOCATION NOT KNOWN%')
       UNION SELECT SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_ID
               --            ,SYSTEMS.SITE_NAME
              , CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.CUSTOMER_CODE
               --            , CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.NAME
              , SYSTEMS.SERIAL_NO
              , SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_TYPE
              , PM.DESCRIPTION
               --            ,MAX(EI.END_DATE)
              , MAX(EI.END_DATE) AS "QCare_End"
              , TO_DATE(NULL) "Warranty_End"
        --            ,MAX(systems.warranty_end)
        --            ,systems.warranty_code
          FROM LEO.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES
               -- , LEO.CUSTOMERS CUSTOMERS
              , LEO.SYSTEMS       SYSTEMS
              , LEO.EXHIBIT_ITEMS EI
              , LEO.PART_MASTER   PM
         WHERE SYSTEMS.ADDRESS_CODE = CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.ADDRESS_CODE
              -- AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.CUSTOMER_CODE = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_CODE 
           AND SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_ID = EI.SYSTEM_ID
           AND SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_TYPE = PM.PART_NO
         GROUP BY SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_ID,
                  SYSTEMS.SERIAL_NO,
                  CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.CUSTOMER_CODE,
                  CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.NAME,
                  SYSTEMS.SITE_NAME,
                  SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_TYPE,
                  PM.DESCRIPTION
        HAVING(SYSTEMS.SYSTEM_TYPE NOT IN('COMPLETE',  'ESSENTIAL', 'LOAN DEMO', 'LOAN CUSTOMER'
        , 'MISC', 'ORPH-CHILD-SYS', 'ORPH_CHILD_SYS', 'PROD-BOM', 'QCARE', 'QSUPPORT', 'SPARES', 'STANDARD', 'WARRANTY', 'SOFT CARE')) 
        AND (SYSTEMS.SITE_NAME NOT LIKE '%DO NOT USE%' AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.NAME NOT LIKE 'QUANTEL%' AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES.NAME NOT LIKE '%LOCATION NOT KNOWN%'))
where ROWNUM <= 10 ORDER BY SERIAL_NO;
```

This just returns 10 results, and it seems pretty sane - but if I re-add the qcare and warranty end dates, it fails with the following error:

> 65  where ROWNUM <= 10 ORDER BY SERIAL_NO;
>       || system_id || ''',''' || customer_code || ''',''' || serial_no || ''',''' || system_type || ''',''' || description ||  ''','''
>   ||qcare_end|| ''',''' ||warranty_end|| ''')'
>                                                                                                                                                                * ERROR at line 3: ORA-00904: "WARRANTY_END": invalid identifier
>
> SQL>

I'm not sure why table aliases wouldn't work - it seems to be fine in regular queries, but not when I'm trying to generate the import statements that I can then pipe into mysql periodically.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?
Cheers
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott,

The aliases don't work because you've put them in double quotes and in mixed case (hint: don't do that). That means you have to reference them that way:

```
SELECT "qcare" FROM (your_query)
```

You probably want this instead, which makes your aliases all upper case:

```
, TO_DATE(NULL) AS qcare_end
, MAX(systems.warranty_end) AS warranty_end
```

And

```
, MAX(EI.END_DATE) AS QCare_End
, TO_DATE(NULL) Warranty_End
```

Technically, you don't need the aliases in the second half of the union anyway, it's the first half of the union that drives the column names for the in-line view.

Comment: Thanks very much DCookie - will try that this afternoon, - I didn't know that about not needing the aliases for the 2nd half of the union - many thanks!